# QGIS error while opening properties programmatically of added layer

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, error

QGIS crashes when I try open properties of programmatically added vector layer, but when I save project and reload everything is ok. I use QGIS 3.10, but I tried also on 3.12. Only QGIS on Linux version 3.4 work fine.

My code:

```py
def add_data_layer(self, name="edge.csv", isResult=False):
    path = os.path.join(self.path, name)
    if os.path.exists(path):
        print(path)
        url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(path)
        query = QUrlQuery()
        query.addQueryItem("delimiter", '|')
        query.addQueryItem("wktField", "wkt")
        url.setQuery(query)
        layer_csv = QgsVectorLayer(str(url.toEncoded())[2:-1], name, 'delimitedtext')
        layer_csv = self.set_layer_format(layer_csv, isResult)
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer_csv)

def set_layer_format(self, layer, isResult=False):

    layer_settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()

    text_format = QgsTextFormat()
    text_format.setFont(QFont("Arial", 12))
    text_format.setSize(12)

    buffer_settings = QgsTextBufferSettings()
    buffer_settings.setEnabled(True)
    buffer_settings.setSize(0.10)
    buffer_settings.setColor(QColor("black"))
    text_format.setBuffer(buffer_settings)

    layer_settings.setFormat(text_format)
    layer_settings.fieldName = self.set_label(isResult)
    layer_settings.placement = 2
    layer_settings.enabled = True
    layer_settings.isExpression = True
    layer_settings = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(layer_settings)

    layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
    layer.setLabeling(layer_settings)
    layer.triggerRepaint()

    return layer
```

Traceback:

```py
QgsStyleProxyModel::QgsStyleProxyModel qgsstylemodel.cpp:860
QgsStyleItemsListWidget::setStyle qgsstyleitemslistwidget.cpp:134
QgsSymbolsListWidget::QgsSymbolsListWidget qgssymbolslistwidget.cpp:42
QgsSymbolSelectorWidget::layerChanged qgssymbolselectordialog.cpp:527
QMetaObject::activate :
QItemSelectionModel::setCurrentIndex :
QAbstractItemView::setCurrentIndex :
QgsSymbolSelectorWidget::QgsSymbolSelectorWidget qgssymbolselectordialog.cpp:306
QgsSingleSymbolRendererWidget::QgsSingleSymbolRendererWidget qgssinglesymbolrendererwidget.cpp:57
QgsSingleSymbolRendererWidget::create qgssinglesymbolrendererwidget.cpp:32
QgsRendererPropertiesDialog::rendererChanged qgsrendererpropertiesdialog.cpp:251
QMetaObject::activate :
QWidgetLineControl::`default constructor closure' :
QComboBox::setCurrentIndex :
QComboBox::setCurrentIndex :
QgsRendererPropertiesDialog::syncToLayer qgsrendererpropertiesdialog.cpp:387
QgsRendererPropertiesDialog::QgsRendererPropertiesDialog qgsrendererpropertiesdialog.cpp:122
QgsLayerStylingWidget::updateCurrentWidgetLayer qgslayerstylingwidget.cpp:419
QMetaObject::activate :
QListWidgetItem::`default constructor closure' :
QMetaObject::activate :
QItemSelectionModel::setCurrentIndex :
QListWidget::setCurrentRow :
QgsLayerStylingWidget::setLayer qgslayerstylingwidget.cpp:254
QMetaObject::activate :
QgsMapLayerComboBox::layerChanged moc_qgsmaplayercombobox.cpp:204
QMetaObject::activate :
QAbstractItemModel::endInsertRows :
QSortFilterProxyModel::insertRows :
QSortFilterProxyModel::sortRole :
QSortFilterProxyModel::`default constructor closure' :
QMetaObject::activate :
QAbstractItemModel::endInsertRows :
QgsMapLayerModel::addLayers qgsmaplayermodel.cpp:172
QMetaObject::activate :
QgsProject::layersAdded moc_qgsproject.cpp:1133
QMetaObject::activate :
QgsMapLayerStore::layersAdded moc_qgsmaplayerstore.cpp:314
QgsMapLayerStore::addMapLayers qgsmaplayerstore.cpp:99
QgsProject::addMapLayers qgsproject.cpp:3065
QgsProject::addMapLayer qgsproject.cpp:3103
meth_QgsProject_addMapLayer sip_corepart1.cpp:159821
```

Comment: This is a bug report, please create it at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/

Comment: Does QGIS crash if you open this csv using the GUI?

Comment: No, only using script or python console.

Comment: And if to skip set_layer_format?